# How get() works in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, get

Say we have Angular Reactive form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <input formControlName="username">
 <div *ngIf="form.get('username').invalid">Invalid</div>
</form>
```

And component:

```
export class FormClass {
 form = new FormGroup({
  username: new FormControl('', Validators.required); 
 )}
}
```

To make this line shorter -
     `<div *ngIf="form.get('username').invalid">Invalid</div>`

We add a get method to the component:

```
get username() {
 return this.form.get('username')
}
```

So now we can do -
 `<div *ngIf="username.invalid">Invalid</div>`

I wonder why we don't **call** this method? We just pass it as a kind of object - without `()`. I mean this method is a function and function gets invoked like this `username()`. Is `get()` somehow special in this case? Sorry for my bad TS knowledge...

Comment: because that's how getters/setters work in JS, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: It's a good question, and I think it can be confusing if you are not used to it in other languages (like Java). There are named getters and setters. I am not good at explaining, but you can find  many questions well answered here on SO, just look for getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will read about it. And @Maximus - I have visited that page before, just reading / understanding docs is still a bit hard for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by adding `get` makes it a getter and can be accessed (read) like a field. This is a TypeScript feature.

With `set` you can create a matching setter and with both you can read and set it like a field.

Comment: I hope your profile image was made at least 20 years ago. Thanks for answer, now its a bit more clear to me

Comment: getter alkways returns a new instance of object?

Comment: @MeganClerc it's about the getter, it's about the implementation of the getter. If you have a getter like `get foo() { return { bar: 'baz'}; }` then every time it will be called a new `{ bar: 'baz'}` will be created and that will drive Angular change detection cracy.